# How to structure this Android layout?

Tags: android, layout, format

I starting developing an android app on version 1.5 of android as per following a series of different books suggesting to always make your app backward compatible. this was fine until I discovered that 1.5 does not handle multiple screen support and so I followed the guidelines from the android pages to overcome this and had to move to 1.6,

After doing this, when I ran the app in the emulator (1.6 version) I found that when switching between landscape portrait (I have two different layouts for these) on going back to portrait, some of the elements on screen would move.

the layout type I had been using is a relative one. So I thought I'd try a table layout instead but I am struggling for that to work.

My basic layout is as follows:

```
(Left top of parent)EditText1           LargeTextView          EditText2(right top of parent)
radiobutton (underneath editText1)  smallTextView (smalltextview) smallTextview radiobutton (under editext2)
TextView (under edittext1)                                       Textview (under editext2)

Image1 Image2 Image3 Image4 
Image5 Image6 Image7 Image8

(smaller images will build here via code)       Animation (not big; just a spinning text)
```

this is the portrait version above and the landscape is pretty much the same in design

Am I better sticking with the relative layout or try and muster a table layout?

Comment: If it is any help, I am using a Mac and running indigo eclipse with the SDK. I have since tried adding a radiobutton on a relative layout with wrap_content set for width and height and the radio button does not appear correctly. It only shows a part of it.

Comment: Furthermore is there always going to be issues with the GUI designer in eclipse ? as this is where most of the design issues are. However sometimes it does not always show them correctly on the device.

Comment: I think I know what might of happened here - when I followed the guide from the android site on how to make the app have a minimum sdk level of 1.5 and a target of 1.6 with a build of 1.6 it is not the same as creating a new project on 1.6. I think I need to somehow create a new project under 1.6 and move all of my 1.5 code etc over - any hints on this?